# Character encoding issue with tomcat version 7.0.73

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, tomcat

I have got to know that the latest version of tomcat(7.0.73) does not allow the special characters `|`,`{`,`}` etc. when a `GET` request is made, would it show the same behaviour when request is made via `ajax` call (`$.ajax{type:"GET"}`)?

Comment: Tomcat 8 is the latest version of Tomcat ... and can you give a little more detail about where these special characters occur?

Comment: the special characters occur in request params

Comment: Can't you just URL Encode them before making the request?

Comment: there are too many number of places in the project to encode. Thats y asking if any solution is available